# Use WP_Query() to Output the 4th to 6th Most Recent Posts of a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have a front page of a site that consists of different custom post types.

To achieve this I've been using the `WP_Query();` function.

In the example below, the query is used in a section and outputs the first 3 posts of the 'news' custom post type.

Is it possible to have a WP_Query where you output a certain range of posts i.e. In a different section I would like to output posts 4-6 of this same 'news' custom post type, not 1-3 (using the default published date as the criteria so it basically shows the 4th, 5th and 6th oldest posts).

Because this is dynamic content I would like it so it always shows posts 4-6 so I don't have to manually change a date range.

Any help would be amazing.

```
<?php 
    $homePageNews = new WP_Query(array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type'=> 'news'
    ));

    while($homePageNews->have_posts()){
        $homePageNews->the_post(); ?>

            // HTML OUTPUT


<?php } ?>

<?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, can achieve this with the `offset` parameter.

```
$homePageNews = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset'         => 3,
    'post_type'      => 'news'
) );
```

That will get 3 posts, but offset by 3, so that you get the 4th to 6th posts.

Comment: Thanks Jacob that worked a treat. Such a shame someone downvoted the question. Why do people do that?